# Need to collect SQL DML statements used by Java application

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, dml

I routinely create new database tables or add new columns to existing database tables for next release of the software. The software is written in Java. Developers also use Hebernate and Exclipse.

Before the implementation I need to review the SQL DML that the application will use against the new database table or column for performance reasons. AKA run-time SQL.

I have scanned the Java code and no SQL is found in the code.

What is the best way to collect only the new SQL that is being added by this release?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your Java application is written, you can:

1) add the following to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

2) add the following under  section of hibernate  in persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>   
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Mybatis Migrations or a similar tool to keep track of changes in database schema.
This way you would have full control on database schema evolution